# How do I check if an integer is sorted (both sides)

Tags: c, function

I managed to check if an integer is sorted from right to left, but how can I check from left to right? Maybe I should do 2 functions, one checks from left to right and the other checks from right to left? For example, I replace `return 0;` with the second function which checks if it's sorted from left to right. I believe this will work. but is there another way to check from both ends without using another function?

Example of numbers that are sorted:

```
1234
4321
4332
2334
```

and these are not sorted:

```
1232
4325
4334
2332
```

Comment: for example return 1 if is sorted from left to right, -1 if sorted from right to left, 0 otherwise

Comment: Perhaps return a `bool`?

Answer (score 4):

This function check both directions:

```
int IsDigitsInNumberSorted( int num )
{
    int leftToRight = 0;
    int rightToLeft = 9;
    while( num > 0 ) {
        const int digit = num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
        if( leftToRight <= digit ) {
            leftToRight = digit;
        } else {
            leftToRight = 10;
            if( rightToLeft == -1 ) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if( digit <= rightToLeft ) {
            rightToLeft = digit;
        } else {
            rightToLeft = -1;
            if( leftToRight == 10 ) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use additional `delta` to check if the digits are changing in the same order or not.

Example,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digitSorted(int num)
{
    int i, rightDigit, nextDigit;
    int delta_1 = 0, delta_2 = 0;
    rightDigit = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    while(num != 0)
    {
        nextDigit = num % 10;
        delta_2 = nextDigit - rightDigit; // << what is the difference between two adjacent digits
        if( delta_1 * delta_2 < 0 )  // << if direction changes, then it is not sorted
            return 0;
        rightDigit = nextDigit;
        num /= 10;
        if( delta_2 != 0 )
            delta_1 = delta_2;    // << save previous change
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 12345;
    printf( "x = %d, sorted = %d\n", x, digitSorted(x) );

    int y = 123453;
    printf( "y = %d, sorted = %d\n", y, digitSorted(y) );

    int z = 54321;
    printf( "z = %d, sorted = %d\n", z, digitSorted(z) );

}
```

---

Output:

```
x = 12345, sorted = 1
y = 123453, sorted = 0
z = 54321, sorted = 1
```

Comment: If all you care about is sign, you can drop the `delta_1 = delta_2;` line, since you were return if the sign ever changed.

Edit: Ahh, just noticed your deltas are initialized to 0.

Comment: Yeah that's how it works. You'll need that to keep track of the differences between adjacent digits. If there is any change in the direction (such as up then down, or vice versa), `delta_1 * delta_2` becomes negative, then a unsorted number is detected.

Comment: What I mean is once initialized to a non-zero value, the sign will never change. You would return instead before the update. Potentially you could hoist that line out of the loop. But I see now with your initialization, that would be inconvenient.

Comment: yeah right, add check for that case, only save previous change if it's non-zero: `if( delta_2 != 0 )`. thanks @user3121023

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

This solution would work for you if you are willing to use c++ way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct Comp{
    Comp():result(true),c_prev(0){}
    bool result;
    char c_prev;
    void operator()(char& c){
        if(c_prev == 0){
            c_prev=c;
            return;
        }
        if(!isdigit(c)) //to handle '-' or '+'
            return;
        result &= c_prev<=c;
        c_prev = c;
    }
};

bool digitSorted(int num, bool left2right=true){
    std::ostringstream sst; sst<<num;
    std::string str = sst.str();
    Comp result;
    if(left2right)
        result = std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), Comp());
    else
        result = std::for_each(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), Comp());

    return result.result;
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting solution anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it with the same function given by you, but simple solution that I find is use a flag variable. In addition to check for the increasing order check decreasing order too and give distinct flag values for both of them and return flag. This will do.

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>


int leftToRight(int num);
int RightToLeft(int num);
int isSorted = 0;

int main()
{

    int num1; //Variable decleration
    printf("Please enter a number: "); //output a string
    scanf("%ld", &num1); //input a number
    leftToRight(num1);
    if (isSorted == 0)
        printf("It is sorted");
    else
        printf("It is not sorted.");

    getch();
}

int leftToRight(int num)
{
    int rightDigit, nextDigit;
    rightDigit = num % 10;
    int temp = num;
    num /= 10;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        nextDigit = num % 10;
        if (nextDigit > rightDigit)
            isSorted--;
        rightDigit = nextDigit;
        num /= 10;
    }
    if (isSorted == 0)
        return isSorted;
    else
         RightToLeft(temp);
}

int RightToLeft(int num)
{
    isSorted = 0;
    int rightDigit, nextDigit;
    rightDigit = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    while (num != 0)
    {
        nextDigit = num % 10;
        if (nextDigit < rightDigit)
            isSorted--;
        rightDigit = nextDigit;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return isSorted;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this wouldn't compile but I could be wrong... The return value from `RightToLeft` is not used in `leftToRight`.... Also what if the user called `RighToLeft` first?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 It goes to leftToRight first, if isn't sorted from left to right, it goes to check if it's sorted from RightToLeft.

Comment: leftToRight lacks a `return` statement

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 because if leftToRight is sorted, it goes to RightToLeft to check there. otherwise, it returns 0.

Comment: Oh I see. You're modifying a global variable instead of using the return values... In that case the return types and the return statement are superfluous

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Exactly.